# Two different senarios to train only the last layer of a convolutional neural network

Tags: neural-networks, classification, transfer-learning

I have a convolutional neural network that has already been trained on data A. The network consists of feature extraction layers and two classification layers. I have trained only it's last classification layer on data B from scratch(without initial weights trained on data A!).

For that purpose, I followed two different scenarios which result significantly different. Could anyone help me figure out this big difference?

Scenario 1 results

AUC=0.53  Accuracy=0.50  Precision=0.58 F1-Score=0.51 Sensitivity=0.50 Specificity=0.44

Scenario 2 results

AUC=0.66  Accuracy=0.63  Precision=0.70 F1-Score=0.64 Sensitivity=0.63 Specificity=0.56

````
Scenario 1
#creating a network:
classifying_network = Classifier(parameters[0],parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3],    parameters[4])    
#get the state_dict:
state_dict=classifying_network.state_dict()

#load the optimal weights trained on data A for all feature extraction and two classification layers:
optimal_weights=torch.load(folder_with_networks+network+'/optimal_weights')
#create new weight dictionary that has weights for all the layers except the last one which would be random initial values from the state dict:
optimal_weights_withfirstclassificationlayer_secondrandom=optimal_weights
optimal_weights_withfirstclassificationlayer_secondrandom['classifier.2.weight']=state_dict['classifier.2.weight']
optimal_weights_withfirstclassificationlayer_secondrandom['classifier.2.bias']=state_dict['classifier.2.bias']
#load the weights:
classifying_network.load_state_dict(torch.load(folder_with_networks+network+'/optimal_weights_withfirstclassificationlayer_secondrandom'))
    
#training the last layer after freezing feature extraction layers and first classification layer
classifying_network.freeze_feature_extraction_first_classification()```

Scenario 2
#read the weights trained on data A previously:
optimal_weights=torch.load(folder_with_networks+network+'/optimal_weights')
#delete last layer
optimal_weights_withfirstclassificationlayer={k:v for k,v in optimal_weights.items() if k !='classifier.2.weight' and k !='classifier.2.bias'}
torch.save(optimal_weights_withfirstclassificationlayer,folder_with_networks+network+'/optimal_weights_withfirstclassificationlayer')

#creating a network without the last layer:
classifying_network = Classifiernolastlayer(parameters[0],parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], parameters[4])
#load the weights dictionary mentioned above 
classifying_network.load_state_dict(torch.load(folder_with_networks+network+'/optimal_weights_withfirstclassificationlayer'))
#add a new layer
classifying_network.classifier.append(nn.Linear(256,1))
#training the last layer after freezing feature extraction layers and first classification layer
classifying_network.freeze_feature_extraction_first_classification()
````